# Spring boot embedded container - Web Server Predictable Session ID Vulnerability

Tags: security, session, spring-boot, spring-security, session-cookies

We use Spring boot with embedded container.

Some security tool gives the following comments for security audit.

"Web Server Predictable Session ID Vulnerability"

"Percentage of common characters among subsequent cookies: 100%"

**Solution from Web:-**

```
Use strong cryptographic algorithms to generate random session IDS.
The Web application should not rely on predictable session IDs as the sole means of session tracking and management.
Any meaningful data being used in session IDs should be one-way encrypted.
```

Not sure how to achieve this in Spring boot embedded container. Should this be done on the load balancer or Does it require any code changes in the Application side?

Comment: Spring Security doesn't generate the session identifiers that is something your servlet container does.

Comment: We use spring boot embedded jetty container.

Comment: It still isn't spring security or any other spring component issuing session tokens, it still is the container. Regardless if it is embedded or not.

Comment: I agree. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Any solutions for this ?

Comment: Has anyone found any solution for this ?